# My shell script run perfectly by putty command but when I put it in crontab it doesnot work

Tags: linux, shell

I have two shell script named: `backup_inventory_sourcecode.sh` and `backup_bash.sh`. I run these two .sh file using as putty as follows:

```
sh /var/www/html/backup_inventory_sourcecode.sh
sh /var/www/html/backup_bash.sh
```

it runs successfully and created a zip file and sql file file respectively. The content of backup_inventory_sourcecode.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash

NOW=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")


sudo zip -r /inventory_sourcecode_backup/inventory_backup_${NOW}.zip /var/www/html/inventory -x ".git"

sync
/var/www/html/ftpupload.sh /inventory_sourcecode_backup/inventory_backup_${NOW}.zip
```

and content of backup_bash.sh  is:

```
#!/bin/bash
NOW=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S")
NOW=${NOW}_Inventory
mysqldump -u root -pAplrootuser  db_apl_inventory >/db_backup/${NOW}.sql

#sleep 30
/var/www/html/ftpupload.sh /db_backup/${NOW}.sql
```

Now I put the two lines in crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * sh /var/www/html/backup_inventory_sourcecode.sh
*/1 * * * * sh /var/www/html/backup_bash.sh
```

these should create .zip and .sql file respectively. but it produce only .sql file. It proves only `*/1 * * * * sh /var/www/html/backup_bash.sh` works but not  `*/1 * * * * sh /var/www/html/backup_inventory_sourcecode.sh`. What is the problem.

Comment: scripts from cron run under a different user and with different environment variables. You should make sure that each stage of your script runs fine and put errors into a log file. Then you'll be able to pinpoint the problem

Comment: probably the zip or sudo command is not found. Try to use them with absolute path. Sudo imho is not needed if the cron is run as root

Answer (score 0):

Cron's default path is implementation-dependent, so check your man page.

You can define your own `PATH` variable in your crontab file.

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
*/1 * * * * sh /var/www/html/backup_inventory_sourcecode.sh
*/1 * * * * sh /var/www/html/backup_bash.sh
```

Comment: but when I access the remote server I can see the path starting at /var

Comment: The PATH variable in your session and they crontab session is most likely different.